# Change the text alignment of column in subform table via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a subform in which a table object in a MS Access database (MS Access 2013) is display:

```
sbf_view.SourceObject = "TABLE.tbl_target"
```

Now I want the text in a certain column in the table `tbl_target`, a column named `Owner`, to be left aligned (all columns in this subform are right aligned by default). I can do this via the Ribbon menu after marking the column (DATASHEET -> Text Formatting -> align left). In this case only the marked column is left aligned.

How can I now do this via vba?

Answer (score 1):

Set the *TextAlign* property of the control (column) to 1. Example here:

[TextBox.TextAlign Property (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192081.aspx)